# PyZMQ Subscriber doesn't receive messages when working with request socket

Tags: python, sockets, pyzmq

I am working with PyZMQ and I have what seems to be a rather peculiar issue. I have two classes that are wrapping sockets for communication, `MZLSubscriber` and `MZLRequester`. There is a class that contains both of them, `MZLLink`. For each of these, I also have tests `MZLSubscriberTest`, `MZLRequesterTest`, and `MZLinkTest`. The tests for the subscriber and requester work as they should, but `MZLinkTest` does not receive any subscriber messages.

Below is what seems to be the relative code, which are the constructors for the 3 classes as well as `run()` for `MZLSubscriber` and the tests for `MZLink` and `MZLSubscriber`.

`MZLink` Constructor:

```
    # Host information
    self.host = host
    self.requestPort = requestPort
    self.subscriberPort = subscriberPort

    # Set up zmq context
    self.zmq_context = zmq.Context()

    # Set up subscriber and replier
    self.subscriber = MZLSubscriber(self.zmq_context, self.host, self.subscriberPort)
    self.requester = MZLRequester(self.zmq_context, self.host, self.requestPort)

    # Start subscriber
    self.subscriber.start()
```

`MZLink` Test:

```
# Constants
HOST = "localhost"
REQ_PORT = 5555
SUB_PORT = 5556

# Create Link
link = MIDASZMQLink(HOST, REQ_PORT, SUB_PORT)

link.close()
```

`MZLRequester` Constructor:

```
    # Initialize class member variables
    self.zmq_context = zmq_context
    self.host = host
    self.port = port

    # Set up reply socket
    self.socket = self.zmq_context.socket(zmq.REQ)

    # Connect socket
    self.socket.connect("tcp://{0}:{1}".format(self.host, self.port))
```

`MZLSubscriber` Constructor:

```
   # Initialize parent process
    Process.__init__(self)

    # Store zmq context and connection host/port
    self.zmq_context = zmq_context
    self.host = host
    self.port = port

    # Sockets. Don't set them up here because sockets are not thread safe
    self.socket = None

    # Queue to store data in
    # TODO: Make queue not overflow if events come in too quickly
    self.queue = Queue()
```

`MZLSubscriber.run()`:

```
    # Parent call
    Process.run(self)

    # Set up subscriber socket in this thread
    self.socket = self.zmq_context.socket(zmq.SUB)
    self.socket.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, unicode())

    # Connect socket
    self.socket.connect("tcp://{0}:{1}".format(self.host, self.port))

    # While the thread is alive, poll for data to put into queue
    # Calling MZLSubscriber.stop() will automatically change this
    while self.is_alive():
        datum = self.socket.recv()
        self.queue.put(datum)

    # Disconnect and close socket.
    #FIXME: Doesn't get here because terminate() immediately stops the process
    self.socket.disconnect("tcp://{0}:{1}".format(self.host, self.port))
    self.socket.close()
```

`MZLSubscriber` Test:

```
# Host information
HOST = "localhost"
SUBSCRIBER_PORT = "5556"

# Set up zmq context
zmq_context = zmq.Context()

# Set up subscriber
subscriber = MZLSubscriber(zmq_context, HOST, SUBSCRIBER_PORT)

# Start subscriber
subscriber.start()

# Stop and join subscriber
subscriber.close()
subscriber.join()
```

The subscriber thread seems to block at `datum = self.socket.recv()`, which makes me think it could be some issue with the socket creation. However, it does seem to work when only working with the subscriber. The requester seems to work in both cases. In addition, everything goes smoothly by just commenting out the two lines dealing with `requester`.

I apologize for the wall of code, but I can't even narrow what code the issue is coming from at this point. When I do, I'll remove the irrelevant code. The test code that deals with the incoming data has been removed.

As a bit of clarification, I am using Python 2.7 with PyZMQ 14.3.1.

**UPDATE:** It seems that running `MZLSubscriber` in the main thread rather than creating another `Process` results in the expected result, so it seems that this could be some sort of thread safety. To my knowledge, zmq contexts are thread-safe, but sockets are not. I thought this wouldn't cause an issue because I'm explicitly making sure there is a socket for each thread.

**UPDATE 2:** If the calls setting up the socket in `MZLSubscriber` are moved from `run()` to `__init__`, the socket seems to receive a small portion of the published message, but does have an error:

```
Process MZLSubscriber-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/Users/user/Repos/midas-client/client/midasclient/mzlSubscriber.py", line 45, in run
    datum = self.socket.recv()
  File "socket.pyx", line 628, in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.recv (zmq/backend/cython/socket.c:5616)
  File "socket.pyx", line 662, in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.recv (zmq/backend/cython/socket.c:5436)
  File "socket.pyx", line 139, in zmq.backend.cython.socket._recv_copy (zmq/backend/cython/socket.c:1771)
  File "checkrc.pxd", line 21, in zmq.backend.cython.checkrc._check_rc (zmq/backend/cython/socket.c:6032)
ZMQError: Interrupted system call
```

I have gotten a workaround to this by creating a new `zmq.Context` in `MZLSubscriber.run()`, although I feel that this shouldn't be necessary if zmq contexts are thread-safe.

Comment: so am I correct in my understanding that `MZLSubscriber` is receiving the published messages but `MZLLink` isn't?

Comment: @ballsdotballs When `MZLSubscriber` is working alone, it receives the published messages, but does not when it is a member of `MZLink`. In the past, I've had issues with forgetting to set the filter, but since that is done during `MZLSubscriber.run()`, I don't think that should be an issue.

Comment: If it is blocking at `socket.recv()`, then it would appear that it is working as it should, but not getting any published messages on that port.  Have you check to ensure that your ports are correct?  As in, you didn't accidentally swap them in `MZLink.__init__()`?

Comment: @ballsdotballs That would make sense, but I have checked them several times. Just to make sure, I tested sending some messages with the requester in `MZLink`,  which worked exactly as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that my issue was using multiple zmq contexts over different processes. While the PyZMQ documentation states that the zmq context is thread-safe, I can only assume it meant Python threads rather than processes. This is quite confusing as in C, zmq contexts are thread safe despite running in a way similar to the Python `multiprocessing.Process`.

The issue was solved by creating a zmq context for each Process.